# Delete iPhone app version in iTunes connect?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have an app that has a great version 1. Very few bugs, etc. I sent in a update (2.0) and it's extremely buggy and apple accepted it. I didn't know it was that buggy when I submitted it - so I changed the availability date to the future. I am working on fixing it.

So my questions is - Can I delete this 'buggy' v2 and revert back to v1 so my app won't be off the market like it is now?

On the versions page, it will only show version 2 and a blank spot to add a version. Was version 1 erased?

Been searching for about an hour and haven't found anything yet. Thanks in advance! Coulton

Comment: You may get better responses by posting this in the Apple developer forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have not yet released version 2, then Apple still has the binary for version 1 and you can delete the binary version 2 and/or resubmit it at a later date.

If version 2 is released already (folks can download it from iTunes), then Apple no longer has version 1. In this case, you could release version 2.1 and have the app be the version 1 release, but you'll have to re-upload the binary for version 1 (hopefully you archived it). A poor but possible option is to release a new version 1.1 that is the old version 1 and have this replace version 2. Apple does not require version numbers to ascend (though good sense does, but you may have a strong case in this situation).

Answer (score 7):

If the app binary is already sent to iTunes Connect, but not been approved, do the following to get it "rejected by developer" (so you can upload new binary):

**Step by step**

1. In iTunes Connect click "view details" on the new version
2. Click on "binary details" to the upper right
3. Then press a greyed button to the upper right to reject the binary

Now you can press "ready to upload binary" whenever you would like to update a correct version.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven;t uploaded the next version build then surely you will have the availability of old version.Once apple approves the new version then & then only new version will be available, then it one can download the old version of apps.

For more details, I suggest is through apple guideline.